# Reference to a File sonata admin

Tags: mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin, database

I have two Documents, Question and Image : The Question references one Image.

```
 /**
 *@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="Image") 
 */
protected $image ;
```

When I add the Image field in the back-end using sonata admin bundle :

```
->add('image', 'sonata_type_admin', array('by_reference' => false))
```

The uploading Button appears but when I try to persist the question I got this exception :

> Cannot create a DBRef without an identifier. UnitOfWork::getDocumentIdentifier() did not return an identifier for class ATS\QuizzBundle\Document\Image
>   Any one knows the origin of this error please ?  thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the same problem which has been patched i think, but you should look at it, if it is already pushed then update mongodb if it helps.

https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1017